# Посчитать количество пересылок в radix sort

Tags: c++, сортировка

Как я поняла сравнений в этой сортировке для массива нет.  Считается ли за пересылку то что находится под циклами for

```
void CountSort(int *array, int size, int exp)
{
    int result[size]; // входной массив
    int i, count[10] = {0};

    // Сохраняем количество вхождений в count[]
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        count[(array[i] / exp) % 10]++;

    // Изменить count[i] так чтобы он соджержал фактическое положение этой цифры в выходных данных
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        count[i] += count[i - 1];

    // Создаём выходной массив
    for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        result[count[(array[i] / exp) % 10] - 1] = array[i];
        count[(array[i] / exp) % 10]--;
    }
    // Копируем выходной массив в array[], так что теперь array[] сожержит отсортированные номера по текущей цифре
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = result[i];
        M++;
    }
}

// Основная функция для сортировки array[] размера сайз используя цифровую сортировку
void radixSort(int *array, int size)
{
    // Находим максимальное число чтоб узнать количество цифр
    int max = getMax(array, size);
    // Делаем подсчет для каждой цифры
    // Вместо номера проходной цифры передается опыт 10^z, где z - текущая цифра
    for (int exp = 1; max / exp > 0; exp *= 10)
        CountSort(array, size, exp);
}
```